# How to launch intent with app shortcut id?

Tags: adb

I want to run the NordVPN app by using am start automatically connects to vpn, on my home screen I have a working shortcut. The shortcut code is:

`Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=com.miui.home.launcher.DEEP_SHORTCUT;launchFlags=0x10200000;package=com.nordvpn.android;component=com.nordvpn.android/.MainActivity;S.shortcut_id=shortcut-germany-515;end`

I am trying to the same via `adb`:

`am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c com.miui.home.launcher.DEEP_SHORTCUT -n com.nordvpn.android/.MainActivity -e S.shortcut_id shortcut-germany-515`

But that does not work, apps start but don't connect to vpn

Comment: Did you find a solution? `S.` is a string as `-e` than you should use `-e shortcut_id shortcut-germany-515` but it still doesn't work for me. Skipping launcher (`-c`) has the same effect, runs an application without extra variable :-/